# How to set up GHA cache for GO dependencies

Tags: go, caching, github-actions

I want to make my builds faster, and I'm pretty sure the biggest part of my build process is fetching this one dependency that I have.

I'm pretty sure I should use https://github.com/actions/cache for that, I tried example from https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#linux-1

And my `.github/workflows/go.yml` looks like this now

```yaml
name: Go

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: |
          ~/.cache/go-build
          ~/go/pkg/mod
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-go-${{ hashFiles('**/go.sum') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-go-

    - name: Set up Go
      uses: actions/setup-go@v3
      with:
        go-version: 1.20

    # I think the most time consuming is downloading deps, TODO: check out GHA caches
    - name: Build
      run: go build -v ./...
```

But it started to fail with

```
Error: urls_db/database.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3" in any of:
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.2.2/x64/src/pkg/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
```

Before adding the `- uses: actions/cache@v3` the build was successful.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: setup-go includes a caching option, which is by default enabled in v4, did you try that?

Comment: fresh news https://github.blog/changelog/2023-03-24-github-actions-the-setup-go-action-now-enables-caching-by-default/